# Is there a way to get Channel 4 player to work natively in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, flash, drm

CHannel 4 player uses flash and drm. There have been some workarounds.

Is there a way to make it work in Ubuntu without using wine? Any workarounds are ok but no wine.

Comment: I have no problem getting passed the flash error notice after enabling it in chrome. Problem is the notice "The service is not currently available in your region".

Comment: It's a UK service. You can try using a British VPN.  The service works in Windows but not in Ubuntu.  Previously you could install HAL to make it work. But something has changed. Here is the official page explaining why they do not support Linux. http://www.channel4.com/4viewers/faq/name/can-i-use-all-4-using-mac-and-linux/id/400287879